# Can conditional types detect if a type parameter got its default because there were no candidate argument types?

Tags: typescript-generics

In other words, I would like to detect in the type system, if a type parameter was derived from a value or if it got its default from a type constraint.

```
type Test<A extends string | number> = {
    a?: A
}
type Infer<T extends Test<any>> = T extends Test<infer A> ? A : never

const v1 = {}
const v2 = { a: 'a' as string | number }

type X1 = Infer<typeof v1> // = string | number
type X2 = Infer<typeof v2> // = string | number
```

Is there some implementation of the `Infer` type that yields different results for `v1` and `v2`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `T['a']` is `unknown` if no value is given. Apparently, the type constraint for the `A` type parameter does not kick-in here. I am not sure if this behavior exists on purpose, though. Therefore, the following `Infer` type does the trick:

```
type Infer<T extends Test<any>> = unknown extends T['a'] ? true : false
type Y1 = Infer<typeof v1> // = true
type Y2 = Infer<typeof v2> // = false
```